# perforce re-branch (reset dev branch to current status of main branch)

Tags: branch, perforce

I have a dev branch with many changes (files added, deleted...). The dev branch is very different from the main branch.
I want to make my dev branch be exactly the same as the main branch in current state (as if I just created it).
Integrate do not fully match the branches. added files in the dev branch are not being deleted.
What is the best way to do it?
Delete the dev branch and re-create it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Delete the dev branch and re-create it?

If you do this you will probably regret it; Perforce will see that you deleted all those files and try its very best to preserve the apparent intent behind that delete by doing things like propagating the delete back to the mainline at the next opportunity.

The command you want is `p4 copy`:

`p4 copy //depot/main/... //depot/dev/...`

or

`p4 copy -b dev-branch`

(or whatever)

Unless you want the *history* to be exactly as if you'd just created it.  Then:

```
p4 obliterate -y //depot/dev/...
p4 populate //depot/main/... //depot/dev/...
```

Comment: +1 to 'p4 copy'. Resets the branch to match main, but still preserves the work you did in the past. Definitely the best of both worlds.